# Delete query produces two different errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a couple of gridviews in my website. Here's the code:

changeSlides.aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="picPath" 
        DataImageUrlFormatString="PlaceImages/{0}" HeaderText="Picture"  ControlStyle-CssClass="editPhotoGridFormat">
        <ControlStyle CssClass="editPhotoGridFormat"></ControlStyle>
            </asp:ImageField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PicPath" HeaderText="Filename" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" 
            SortExpression="Country" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

EditBlogPost.aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
    AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Gray"  
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="editGridFormat" RowStyle-CssClass="editGridFormat"        
    RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">

    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gray" CssClass="editGridFormat"></AlternatingRowStyle>

    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BlogTitle" HeaderText="BlogTitle" 
            SortExpression="BlogTitle" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image" HeaderText="Image"
            DataImageUrlFormatString="~/PlaceImages/{0}" ControlStyle-CssClass="editPhotoGridFormat"
            AlternateText="Either a wrong file type or a misspelled file name has occurred" 
            NullDisplayText="No picture on file" >
        <ControlStyle CssClass="editPhotoGridFormat"></ControlStyle>
        </asp:ImageField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Caption" 
            HeaderText="Caption for Picture on Homepage" />
        <asp:TemplateField headertext="Text for the homepage">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox id="PicTextBox" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("PicText")%>' textmode="MultiLine" height="300px" width="300px" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("PicText")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TravelDate" HeaderText="Date of Travel" 
            SortExpression="TravelDate" DataFormatString="{0:MMMMMMMMM, dd, yyyy }" HtmlEncode="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField headertext="Top of the Blog Post">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox id="BeginTextBox" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("BeginText")%>' textmode="MultiLine" height="300px" width="300px" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("BeginText")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" 
            SortExpression="Country" />
        <asp:TemplateField headertext="Text at the End of the Post">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox id="EndTextBox" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("EndText")%>' textmode="MultiLine" height="300px" width="300px" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("EndText")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

<RowStyle VerticalAlign="Top" CssClass="editGridFormat"></RowStyle>    
</asp:GridView>
```

EditPeoplePhotos.aspx:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" Width="493px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" 
            ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="picPath" 
            DataImageUrlFormatString="photos/PeoplePhotos/{0}" HeaderText="Picture"  ControlStyle-CssClass="editPhotoGridFormat">
        </asp:ImageField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My update statements work, but my delete statements don't work in two of the three gridviews. My corresponding delete statements are all virtually the same: "DELETE FROM (Table Name) WHERE ID=?" but I get different error codes, which are as follows:

For changeSlides.aspx, it says "Entry with same key already exists"
For EditBlogPosts.aspx, it work fine. It deletes the blog.
For EditPeoplePhotos.aspx, it says "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Each of those pages use a separate, unrelated table in my database, and each query is only referring to one table, so there are no foreign keys used.

What is going on?

Comment: Are you using foreign key? Please add your table structure to your question and the sql queries you use.

Comment: @Narendra I have updated the question to talk about my database structure. They are all unrelated tables. The query to delete the record really is just what I wrote up there, substituting the name of the table. I used the Visual Studio gridview wizard to generate the UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT statements also.

Comment: For EditPeoplePhotos.aspx, it says "No value given for one or more required parameters" - You are missing some identity columns which is required for delete command. May be its primary key.

Comment: For changeSlides.aspx, it says "Entry with same key already exists" - duplicate records with the same id existis.

Comment: But you can see by my gridview code that I have my ID column, which is my PK, set to be included in my SELECT statement. And I can assure you that in my database, there are no duplicate keys. Why is it working in my EditBlogPosts.aspx, whose delete query is no different?